# Как с помощью стека сделать переход на предыдущую страницу? Javascript

Tags: javascript, стек

Есть такие три страницы: главная (которую не смогла загрузить), входа и, собственно, ваша страница. Как видно, на последних двух есть кнопка Back, которая, по идее, должна возвращать на предыдущую страницу. Т.е. с Входа - на Главную, и со Страницы - на Вход. Но работает так, что со Страницы на Главную, и это не есть хорошо. Мне посоветовали, что это можно сделать стеком, но он мне очень тяжело дается.

1. - [image]
2. - [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работает это как-то так ...

```js
// Создаем массив в который будем складировать историю переходов
let historyArr = [];
// Кнопки для управления переходами
const pageSwitcher = document.getElementsByClassName('page-switcher'),
  pageBack = document.getElementsByClassName('page-back');
  
// Добавляем в историю стартовую страницу
historyArr.push('page-0');

for(let switcher of pageSwitcher) {
  // Вешаем обработчик на кнопки перехода "вперед" (Например: Главная->Логин->Страница пользователя)
  switcher.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Добавляем в конец массива новый "адрес" (в примере это аттрибут data-href)
    historyArr.push(this.dataset.href);
    console.log(historyArr);
  });
}

// Вешаем обработчик на кнопку "назад"
pageBack[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Просто извлекаем значение из нашей "истории"
  // if( historyArr.length > 1 ) - так как нам не нужно, что бы стартовая страница удалялась из истории
  if( historyArr.length > 1 ) historyArr.pop();
  console.log(historyArr);
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <button class="page-switcher" data-href="page-1">Page 1</button>
  <button class="page-switcher" data-href="page-2">Page 2</button>
  <button class="page-switcher" data-href="page-3">Page 3</button>
  <button class="page-switcher" data-href="page-4">Page 4</button>
  <button class="page-back">Back</button>
</div>
```

- Создаем массив с "историей переходов"
- Когда происходит переход на новую страницу, добавляем (`push`) её в "историю" (в данном примере это значение которое хранится в атрибуте `data-href` нашей кнопки)
- Когда нажимаем "Назад", извлекаем (`pop`) последнее значение (текущая страница), в итоге в нашем массиве истории последним элементом (`historyArr[-1]`) становится "название предыдущей страницы" и по нему уже ориентируемся что нам загружать/показывать.

**P.S.** была бы опция "вперед", тогда при извлечении потребовался бы ещё один массив в который бы мы складировали извлеченные "страницы".

**P.S.S.** Хотя лучше это все же делать через History

Comment: Не сразу в этом разобралась, но спасибо большое) Запутанная это штука

Comment: Все что надо понимать: array.push(value) - добавляет значение в массив, array.pop() - изымает последний элемент массива (можно делать var el = array.pop(), тогда el будет содержать изъятый элемент). По сути вы просто делаете "карту ваших переходов", если переходите на новую страницу, добавляете значение array.push(), если идете назад, то "удаляете" последнее значение array.pop(), а уже в зависимости от того, какое у вас текущее последнее значение в массиве определяете какой контент на странице вам отображать.

Comment: @Біпач, и да, если ответ помог и альтернативных решений не требуется, щелк галочку слева вверху ответа ;)